# Trying to create array but creates an object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm currently trying to create an array in php that would have the current format:
calendar[month][row][column], where month = 1 to 6

This is basically the code I used to create it. There's more to it, but I'm hoping this suffices.

```
function db_to_matrix($date_start, $date_end, $compliment, $workers, $worker_shifts, $shift_types)
{
    $calendar = array();
    //Sets the titles up for each months array
    $date = clone $date_start;
    while ($date <= $date_end)
    {
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')] = array();
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][0][] = "db_table";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][0][] = "id";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][0][] = "";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][1][] = "";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][1][] = "";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][1][] = "";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][2][] = "compliment";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][2][] = "compliment_day";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][2][] = "Day Comp";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][3][] = "compliment";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][3][] = "compliment_day_actual";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][3][] = "Act Day";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][4][] = "compliment";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][4][] = "compliment_night";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][4][] = "Night Comp";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][5][] = "compliment";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][5][] = "compliment_night_actual";
        $calendar[date_format($date,'n')][5][] = "Act Night";
        date_modify($date,"+1 month");
    }
}
```

What I end up with is the following:

Object {1: Array[95], 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object}

I'm ok with $calendar being an object, but every "variable" after that I would like to get Array. Example: Object {1: Array[95], 2: Array[95], 3: Array[95], 4: Array[95], 5: Array[95], 6: Array[95]}

Comment: Why are you creating a array with index as date?

Comment: the "date" can equal 1-6 as my example... OR it can be 3-6 or 6-12 as well...

Comment: I'm new to PHP so may be completely off target but shouldn't a value be passed to the column element? eg `$calendar[date_format($date,'n')][0][**3**] = "db_table";`

Comment: @Bendy: No. `[]` appends a new element. So you would get `[0][0], [0][1], [0][2]`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - thanks, I'll keep quiet ;-)

Comment: This code seems to be working just fine... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6220775b9dac84453ee9022de446b0305949af9f   Just run it from there, and youll see it does exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You may be re-using a variable, try using a different variable name or reset $calendar as an array before the while loop.

`$calendar = array();`

Comment: I'd put money on it,  that this is the reason in this case , since my PHP sandbox example works fine...lol

Comment: that did not work. I changed my code above to show. Same output.